# Struggling to connect my SQLite db android studio, table has no column to insert

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

So I'm trying to setup my `SQLite` database but I'm receiving errors which I'm finding difficult to correct.
[See the error log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXL8k.png)

Theres an image of the error being thrown and heres my code setup for my DatabaseHelper

I've also received some other errors in my log which I'm not sure what they are related to - any info be great
[see the logcat output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UA4M.png)

code of the error anyway

```
  E/SQLiteLog: (1) table my_manager has no column named 
    location_description in "INSERT INTO my_manager(location_name,location_county,location_description) 
    VALUES (?,?,?)"
     2020-11-28 19:56:32.986 5665-5665/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting location_name=Blarney Stone 
     location_county=Cork location_description=Stone in  big wall
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table my_manager has no column named location_description 
     (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 
     my_manager(location_name,location_county,location_description) VALUES (?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        a....
```

And here is my source code:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 
    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_manager.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME =  "my_manager";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "location_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "location_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_COUNTY = "location_county";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "location_description";


    public MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                        " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_COUNTY + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT );";
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);


    }

    void addLocation(String location, String county, String description){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
        cv.put(COLUMN_COUNTY, county);
        cv.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        if (result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added Successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    Cursor readAllData(){
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(db != null){
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine - any chance you added the description column but didn't bump the version?  If in doubt either reinstall app or bump the version (assuming your ok with losing the data - is that really what you want in the upgrade?).

Comment: Thanks no there's no data to be lost .. how do I bump the version/ reinstall the app?

Comment: Set `DATABASE_VERSION` to 2 - that is what triggers the `onUpgrade` to be invoked.  Reinstall app simply means uninstall from emulator or device and reinstall using whatever means you are currently using.

Comment: So I remember some code from my gradel module bundle and carried out a reinstall of the app and cold booted after, worked the charm thank you! Would you mind explaining the issue that was there so I can learn from it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you first run your app the `onCreate` is executed and the schema at the time of first execution is set and the `DATABASE_VERSION` is associated with that schema.

Every time the super is invoked in the constructor (`super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);`) the SQLiteOpenHelper code looks at the database version number and if its greater than last defined than the `onUpgrade` is invoked.

During initial development it is common to alter the schema as you are adding to your App before first release.  In this mode you have two choices:

1. Uninstall and reinstall App everytime the schema changes (loss of data).  This causes the initial `onCreate` to be invoked with new schema again associated with version.
2. Bump the version (just needs to be higher than previous version) and the `onUpgrade` is invoked where you'd likely ALTER TABLE (to add/modify columns) or CREATE TABLE to add new tables.

The second option is normally used when an app is already released and the schema needs to be altered (without data loss).  The end user would receive an App update and the `onUpdate` is invoked (because of the bumped version) and any alterations are applied to their existing database without loss of data (assuming you `onUpgrade` did not intentionally destroy data).

If data loss during initial development is not an issue than the uninstall/reinstall option seems easiest.

If you just alter schema without bumping version then essentially nothing is affected - and therefore when you perform a query on a new column, for example, it complains that it doesn't exist because it was never added.